# JAX-RS not responding (404)

Tags: jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I have a very basic JAX-WS-RS that I'm trying to get working and am getting frustrated. And would love some help. --thanks.

my environment is Eclipse 2018-09 (fresh "dynamic web-app"), java 8u191, tomcat 8.5

my "basic" code (running in the app named: webservice) won't respond at all to calls to /webservice/steve. only a 404.

I'm including JAR: /WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar

code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/")
public class ServletTest {
    @GET
    @Path("/steve")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getSteve() {return "Steve";}
}
```

Comment: You only have the JAX-RS API jar. You need an implementation like Jersey. Tomcat does not have one.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. I'll try later tonight. No errors though as I'd expect. Tomcat also doesn't try to load the endoints either.  thanks

Comment: [Download the RI bundle](https://jersey.github.io/download.html), add all the jars to your project, and see the [web.xml configuration](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet)